# c++ is it safe to unget on fstreams

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream

Suppose `input.txt` is 1 byte text file:

```
std::ifstream fin("input.txt", std::ios::in);
fin.get();              // 1st byte extracted
fin.get();              // try to extract 2nd byte
std::cout << fin.eof(); // eof is triggered
fin.unget();            // return back
std::cout << fin.eof(); // eof is now reset
fin.get();              // try to extract 2nd byte, eof assumed
std::cout << fin.eof(); // no eof is triggered
```

Seems like `unget()` breaks `eof` flag triggering also it breaks file pointers. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eof` is not set, but neither is `good`. The stream is ignoring operations because it's in a failure mode.

I cannot recall what `unget` is supposed to do after EOF, but `unget` goes right back into failure if I use `clear` to allow a retry.

http://ideone.com/JkDrwG

It's usually better to use your own buffer. Putback is a hack.

Comment: `unget`:

> After constructing a sentry object, if !good() calls 
setstate(failbit) which may throw an exception, and return.

Comment: @user657267 Yes, but I mean after `clear` from an EOF state, which is what the linked IDEone experiment does.